# What is Fiddle and what is DL?

Tags: ruby

My Operating System is Windows 7

in command line

```
c:>ruby -v

ruby 2.0.0p598 [i368-mingw32]
```

when I type

```
c:>rails -v 

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
```

Rails 4.1.8

Comment: Have you tried google, before asking? It's so easily found if you just search *DL is depricated, please use Fiddle*

Answer (score 1):

`DL` and `Fiddle` are both Ruby libraries. The message, `DL is depricated, please use Fiddle` is a warning message that shows up if you are using Windows.

Under `C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\2.0.0\dl.rb`

There is the line

```
warn "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"
```

You can simply comment this out. It's not an error message, but simply a warning.